# Showing an event driven Toast rather then time

Tags: android, toast

I want to show a "Loading please wait..." Toast during the time while my mediaPlayer.prepareAsync() is loading and then dismiss it in onPrepared(). I am opening a remote stream so this can take longer then a normal Toast.

UPDATE: As it seems that there is no way to control a toast. Is there a way to capture the Toast's view. I want my message to look exactly like the native Toast of the device. This can be customized by the vendor.

What I have found so far:

```
View view = new Toast(this).getView();
```

and:

```
LayoutInflater inflate = (LayoutInflater) getApplicationContext().
            getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
View view = inflate.inflate(com.android.internal.R.layout.transient_notification, null);
TextView tv = (TextView) view.findViewById(com.android.internal.R.id.message);
```

Will this get me a View and if so how to I apply it to make a textView?

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to dismiss a toast. You have to make a dialog and design it for your needs.

Comment: Is it possible then to grab the View of a Toast and use it for a TextView? It seems different devices have slightly different Toast Views and I want my message to look exactly like the native Toast of the device.

Comment: I don't think so, as a toast is not a view itself. But you could explore the android source and grep the background an the text font.

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to make a custom message panel. That shouldn't be hard. You can't control the time or dismissal of a toast.